# Argument Type Problems

Tags: casting, compiler-errors, fortran

Why am I getting the following error

```
  d = Atan ( 1_Real32 / 110443_Real32 )
             1
Error: 'x' argument of 'atan' intrinsic at (1) must 
be REAL or COMPLEX
```

The funny thing is that I get no problems when I use

```
d = Atan ( Real(1,Real32) / Real(110443,Real32) )
```

Comment: 1.0_Real32 / 110443.0_Real32 seems to work although I don't know why 1_Real32 etc fails. BTW If it means real(4) on a common x86_64 platform and no compiler options like -real8 are set, real(4) is the default floating-point kind, so it is no problem to write 1.0 etc with no kind tag (it is equivalent to 1.0_Real32).

Comment: @roygvib There are compilers which use different kind numbers, e.g. NAG where `real(4)` means nothing by default, even on the same platform and without any special flags the kind numbers are NOT 100% portable.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks. Acutally, I implicitly assumed using gfortran or Intel fortran on Linux(x86_64), but one may use different compilers so in that case it may be safer not to assume "default" things.

Comment: I do not support proprietary software like NAG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `1_Real32` is an *int-literal-constant* (R407, Fortran2008 4.4.2.2 5).

To get a real value instead you need to change it to `1._Real32`.  The presence of the decimal makes it a *real-literal-constant* (R413, Fortran2008 4.4.2.3 6).

Remember that `Real32` in your code is just a number, e.g. `4` and it only specifies a kind, not a type e.g. `1_4` is an integer of kind 4 and `1._4` is a real of kind 4.

You don't encounter the error in the second example because the intrinsic `real()` always returns a real value including when supplied an integer as its first argument.

Answer (score 3):

[casey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30428007) is quite correct, but it may be worth making one thing explicit in response to the question.

The intrinsic `real` accepts an integer argument and returns a real of default or specified kind.  Whereas `1_real32` is an integer (if `real32` is a valid kind number for integers) `real(1, real32)` is a real.