# How to cast a real as a specific KIND?

Tags: casting, fortran, precision, fortran90

I have multiple kinds I am using in Fortran and would like to add a real valued number where the real number is cast as that kind.

For example, something like:

```
program illsum
    implicit none

#if defined(USE_SINGLE)
    integer, parameter :: rkind = selected_real_kind(6,37)
#elif defined(USE_DOUBLE)
    integer, parameter :: rkind = selected_real_kind(15,307)
#elif defined(USE_QUAD)
    integer, parameter :: rkind = selected_real_kind(33, 4931)
#endif

    integer :: Nmax = 100 
    integer :: i

    real(kind = rkind) :: mysum = 0.0 

    do i = 1,Nmax
        mysum = mysum + kind(rkind, 1.0)/kind(rkind, i)
    enddo

end program illsum
```

So I want to make sure that `1.0` and the real valued expression of `i` are expressed as the proper kind that I have chosen before performing the division and addition.

How can I cast `1.0` as `rkind`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a numeric value to a real value then there is the `real` intrinsic function.  Further, this takes a second argument which determines the kind value of the result.  So, for your named constant `rkind`

```
real(i, rkind)      ! Returns a real valued i of kind rkind
real(1.0, rkind)    ! Returns a real valued 1 of kind rkind
```

which I think is what you are meaning with `kind(rkind, 1.0)`.  `kind` itself, however, is an intrinsic which returns the kind value of a numeric object.

However, there are other things to note.

First, the literal constant `1._rkind` ([note](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30424557) the `.` in there, could be clearer with `1.0_rkind`) which is of kind `rkind` and value approximating `1`.

There's no comparable expression `i_rkind`, though, so the conversion above would be necessary for a real result of kind `rkind` with value approximating `i`.

That said, for you example there is no need to do such casting of the integer value.  Under the rules of Fortran the expression `1._rkind/i` involves that implicit conversion of `i` and is equivalent to `1._rkind/real(i,rkind)` (and `real(1.0, rkind)/real(i,rkind)`).